# How to make pylint count only arguments without a default value?

Tags: python, pylint

By default, pylint fails (returns errorcode>0) if a method has more than 5 parameters.

```py
def my_func(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
```

will therefore fail. 
I would like to keep this behavior but allow functions that pass default values like

```py
def my_func2(a, b, c, d=None, e='yes', f=1.0, g=None, h=True, i=10)
```

not to fail.

In other words, I would like pylint to only count parameters without default value.
Can this be done? How? Is there a regexp for the parameters?

*Note*: raising `max-args` does not help in this respect since `my_func2` actually receives more parameters than `my-func`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more days of playing around with this I found a workaround.

It is possible to disable specific pylint checks for a specific line of a specific block of code,
as described 
[here](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html).

Since in my case there is a specific function for which I think it is OK to violate the `too-many-arguments` check, I can add as the first line after the function definition the an instruction to pylint to disable the check:

```
def my_func2(a, b, c, d=None, e='yes', f=1.0, g=None, h=True, i=10):
    # pylint: disable=too-many-arguments
    pass
```

This disables the error, and the pylint check completes successfully.

While this is a workaround to my original question I am OK with this solution, 
because it requires the developer to actively say that this is an intentional 
violation of pylint guidelines that is acceptable.